# How do I make the compile of one maven 3 project depend on the install of another?

Tags: maven-3

I have a directory with a pom.xml and several subdirectories with their own pom.xml files

One subdirectory is local called thirdparty. It contains several jar files and installs them to the local maven repo when a `mvn install` is executed. These are needed by the `mvn compile` phase of the other artifacts. The root pom.xml simply executes the same step on each child pom.xml.

I'd like to modify the root pom.xml so that mvn compile will do an install on the third party folder before executing the other folders. I tried this in the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I see nothing in the documentation about specifying a phase in a dependency element.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I have this straight, it sounds like you have an aggregator pom, AGG, and some submodules, A and B, where A is nothing but some third-party jars that have to be installed in the local repo before B will compile. If that's true, then two possibilities spring to mind:

1) Do away with A and instead install the third party jars into an appropriate standalone repo, like a [local Nexus server](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), and add that repo to your pom. That would be the "Maven" way of doing it.

2) Add a dependency on A to B's `<dependencies>`. In A, configure the [install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) with an execution per jar that needs to be installed, and bind these executions to the `compile` phase. Then when you run `compile` on AGG, it will first run `compile` on A, which will install all the jars, followed by `compile` on B. Note that this will have the side effect of producing an A.jar, which will be a dependency of B, because maven assumes that every module produces exactly one artifact of some type. You might be forced to add at least one class or resource so that A.jar can actually be built. Not sure about that one. Alternately, you could experiment with setting A's packaging to "pom".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Maven in a wrong way.

Such kind of 3rd party dependencies should be put to local repository (or your internal Maven repository) before you run the compilation work, and dependencies in your project should be setup accordingly.  "Installation of 3rd party artifacts" shouldn't be part of the build process.

And, in Maven world, we rarely have 3rd party libs exists as part of the source code.  In fact one of the reason for using Maven is to get rid of such kind of libs in source code.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want a couple of dependancies.  Look into the depends element.